# Using present perfect with "for" to refer to a complete event

Tags: tense

Take the sentence below:

> A bike has been in our family for 9 years. My dad **used (1)** it for the first five, and I **have used (2)** it for the last four years.

While that was correct, I initially wrote (1) as "has used". I justified it by thinking that the father stopped using the bike 4 years ago. Up until the point where the statement is made, 4 years later, the dad has just used it for five years. The duration hasn't increased since he completely stopped.

Can I interpret it that way?

Comment: Welcome to the  English Language Learners site! This is a great first question, keep it up!  If you've got a minute, feel free to take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out the [help centre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe it's best to switch the first part of the statement into a past form if you wish to use "has".

That would make it: had used

The present tense for a point in the past "has used" is a bit awkward considering that this event is well into the past.